# The endless cat and mouse game of fail2ban

Tags: fail2ban

I'm not sure if it's a problem to begin with, but the situation is that run Postfix as a mail server on my computer. Almost a year ago because of numerous failed login attempts I installed fail2ban. It does its job. But it's kinda strange for my taste. It bans an IP, after a few hours unbans it, then after half an hour bans again etc. etc. Some bots try to log in once every 20 minutes to escape the ban.

The load average of the server seems to be fine. Approx 0,20

So my question is... Does it all fall within something normal or it requires some action on my part? Or a login attempt once in 20 minutes is something so light for the server so it's best to ignore it?

Answer (score 4):

That's how fail2ban works. You can tune it. Check this [blog post](http://blog.kandiaro.net/2015/02/security/securing-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos/)

From the blog:

```
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
bantime = 600
findtime = 600
maxretry = 3
```

ignoreip – So add the hosts you usually log-in from to ignoreip list separated by a space. This means that fail2ban will not apply these rules to the ip or network you mention here.

bantime – how long do you want to ban the IP addresses for ? Default is 600 seconds which is a good starting point. You can always tweak this if needed.

findtime – fail2ban will ban IP or host if that same host has maxretry attempts during the last findtime. So if someone provides invalid log in information for 3 times in last 600 seconds they get banned for 600 seconds.

maxretry – number of invalid log in attempts before a host is banned. I keep it at 3 but the default is actually 6.

Comment: I can set findtime to something like 2 hours and then the fourth attempt would be within 90 minutes and it would trigger the ban. Though I don't know if it's a good idea overall?

Comment: I tried banning IP for 24 hours but soon realised that it was filling up my iptables rules table and consuming more memory. So your scenario will work but may be try it for a few days and see how your system coups with it.

Comment: It's better for performance to use ipsets for banning, but this requires fail2ban 0.9+ (and possibly systemd).

Comment: In the file /etc/fail2ban/jail.local in its DEFAULT section I have this now:

`2016-10-11 05:48:09,056 fail2ban.filter : INFO Set maxRetry = 2
2016-10-11 05:48:09,057 fail2ban.filter : INFO Set findtime = 5400
2016-10-11 05:48:09,057 fail2ban.actions: INFO Set banTime = 86400`

So even if bots try to log in every 20 minutes, the ban eventually will catch them. And those bots that attempt to log in very often will be banned same as before when I had findtime set to 600 and maxRetry to 3. Correct?

Comment: yes so it will look as far back as 90 minutes, if it finds two failed attempts then it will ban the ip for 24 hours. Also what Michael suggested, I have updated my rules to use IPSet instead of iptables directly. You just have to change the action   = iptables-ipset-proto4[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]